# Help with basic insert trigger after Campaign Member Status update

Tags: trigger, update

This is my first attempt at an insert trigger :)  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Scenario:
If campaign member status gets updated, insert a record on a custom object (Registration).

Code:

```
trigger Insert_Registration_on_member_status_change on CampaignMember (after update) {
List<miiEventV1__Registration__c> reg = new List<miiEventV1__Registration__c>();
    for (miiEventV1__Registration__c c: Trigger.new)
         if (CampaignMember.Status != null){
                 reg.add (new miiEventV1__Registration__c(
                     miiEventV1__Client__c = CampaignMember.Account_ID__c,
                     miiEventV1__Presentation__c = CampaignMember.Related_Presentation__c,
                     miiEventV1__Presentation_Ticket_Type__c =  CampaignMember.Create_Ticket_Id__c,
                     miiEventV1__Status__c = 'Registered',
                     miiEventV1__Active__c = TRUE));   
         }
   insert reg;
}
```

Questions:

1) I copied and modified this code from a tutorial, is this line formatted correctly?

```
    for (miiEventV1__Registration__c c: Trigger.new)
```

2) I keep getting the error message "Invalid initial expression type for field miiEventV1_*Registration*_c.miiEventV1_*Client*_c, expecting: Id". This would apply for the Client_*c and Presentation*_c field as well. Those are all formula fields pulling the record Id value from the related records. Even if I change them to "miiEventV1_*Client*_c = CampaignMember.Contact.Account.Id" etc, I still get the same error message. What do I need to do to feed those fields as values for the new inserted record?

Thank you in advance for your replies!

Regards,

Robin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trigger.new in this context is going to be a collection of CampaignMember objects rather than miiEventV1__Registration__c objects.

The references in your code that are CampaignMember.Account_ID__c, etc. (that explicitly use CampaignMember) are actually retrieving information about that field on the object definition rather than a record of that type of object.

You'll want to change your code to be similar to the following:

```
for (CampaignMember cm : Trigger.new) {
  if (cm.Status__c != null) {
    reg.add(new miiEventV1__Registration__c(miiEventV1__Client__c = cm.Account_ID__c)));
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear Michael, 

Thank you for your prompt response! I modified the code as you suggested and was able to save it without error messages!

I am now stuck on writing the test class, but will open a new topic for it.

Much appreciated!